# How to post google plus feed with google api?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to post on my own google plus feed with sharing public

Is this possible with google plus API ? If so how can i do it with using c# ?

The application will net 4.5 C# WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programmatically or automatically post to the Google+ stream.